# RDF4j and GraphDB repository connection

Tags: graphdb, rdf4j

I've a problem with rdf4j: i want to delete from my GraphDB repository "Feed" all the triples with `feed:hashCode` as predicate.

The first query verifies if there is a triple with the `url` parameter as subject, `feed:hashCode` as predicate, and `hash` parameter has object, and it works. If this statement doesn't exist in my repository, the second query begins, it should delete all the triples  with `feed:hashCode` as predicate and `url` as subject, but it doesn't work, what is the problem?

Here is the code:

```java
public static boolean updateFeedQuery(String url, String hash) throws RDFParseException, RepositoryException, IOException{
    Boolean result=false;
    Repository repository = new SPARQLRepository("http://localhost:7200/repositories/Feed");
    repository.initialize();

    try {
        try (RepositoryConnection conn = repository.getConnection()) {
            BooleanQuery feedUrlQuery = conn.prepareBooleanQuery(
                    // @formatter:off
                    "PREFIX : <http://purl.org/rss/1.0/>\n" +
                    "PREFIX feed: <http://feed.org/>\n" +
                    "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>\n" +
                    "PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>\n" +
                    "ASK{\n" +
                    "<"+url+"> feed:hashCode \""+hash+"\";\n"+
                    "rdf:type :channel.\n" +
                    "}"
                    // @formatter:on
            );

            result = feedUrlQuery.evaluate();

            //the feed is new or updated
            if(result == false) {

                Update removeOldHash = conn.prepareUpdate(
                        // @formatter:off
                        "PREFIX feed: <http://feed.org/>\n" +
                        "DELETE WHERE{\n"+
                        "<"+url+"> feed:hashCode ?s.\n" +
                        "}"
                        // @formatter:on
                        );
                removeOldHash.execute();
            }

        }
    }
    finally {
                 repository.shutDown();
                 return result;
    }

}
```

The error code is: "Missing parameter: query", and the server response is : "400 Bad Request"

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in this line:

```java
Repository repository = new SPARQLRepository("http://localhost:7200/repositories/Feed");
```

You are using `SPARQLRepository` to access your RDF4J/GraphDB triplestore, and you're providing it only with a SPARQL *query* endpoint. According to [the documentation](http://docs.rdf4j.org/javadoc/latest/index.html?org/eclipse/rdf4j/repository/sparql/SPARQLRepository.html), that means it will use that endpoint for both queries and updates. However, RDF4J Server (and therefore GraphDB) has a separate endpoint for SPARQL updates (see the [REST API documentation](http://docs.rdf4j.org/rest-api/#_perform_update_described_in_a_sparql_1_1_update_string)). Your update fails because `SPARQLRepository` tries to send it to the query endpoint, instead of the update endpoint.

One way to fix is to explicitly set an update endpoint as well:

```java
Repository repository = new SPARQLRepository("http://localhost:7200/repositories/Feed", "http://localhost:7200/repositories/Feed/statements");
```

However, `SPARQLRepository` is really intended as a proxy class for accessing a (non-RDF4J) SPARQL endpoint (e.g. DBPedia, or some endpoint outside your own control or running a different triplestore implementation). Since GraphDB is fully RDF4J-compatible, you should really be using the `HTTPRepository` to access it. `HTTPRepository` implements the full RDF4J REST API, which extends the basic SPARQL protocol, which will allow your client-server communication to be much more efficient. See the [Programming with RDF4J chapter on the Repository API](http://docs.rdf4j.org/programming/#_creating_a_repository_object) for more details on how effectively accesss a remote RDF4J/GraphDB store.